# Sony VAIO power button does not react from time to time

Tags: windows-7, power, sony-vaio

I have a brand new Sony VAIO S series, running a non-bloated and non-preinstalled Windows 7 ultimate edition, which randomly? does not react at all when pressing the power button, even when the battery is fully juiced up and with the power adapter connected.

The only solution is to remove the battery and put it back in, after which the power button reacts fine again for a couple of weeks.

What could be the cause of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

"I have a brand new Sony VAIO S series"
This is the most important part of your question.

"What could be the cause of this strange behavior?"
Faulty hardware could be the cause.  In fact, it not only could be the cause, it most probably *is* the cause.  At any rate, it is important to go back to the first statement I quoted.  This is a **BRAND NEW** Vaio.  By any standard definition of that phrase, you have implied that the unit is still under warranty.  This begs the question... why have you not contacted Sony support and arranged for the unit to be shipped back to Sony for repair or replacement for what is obviously a manufacturing defect?

It is not about your ability to repair this, regardless of what is causing the problem.  This is about your ability to use the warranty that came with the unit, and get Sony to repair a problem that never should have been yours to deal with in the first place.

Seriously.

Comment: I've seen this sort of behavior with static buildup - some laptops are very particular about not powering on if there's too much juice in certain capacitors on the motherboard.  You should try pulling the battery *and holding the power button down for ~30 seconds*.  If that gets it to start up after reinstalling the battery, there's your problem...and if it continues to happen after that, get it serviced.  +1 to this for 'don't waste your time with it'.